# How to find if two line segments intersect or not in Java?

Tags: java, algorithm, geometry

I need to implement a method called disjointSegments that returns true if line segments are disjoint and false otherwise.

That's what I have until now. There should be 2 segments, ab and cd.

```
public static boolean disjointSegments(Point2D.Double a, Point2D.Double b,
        Point2D.Double c, Point2D.Double d)
```

This is an assignment and it says that I could figure it out by using delta method, which is a method that computes the determinant of a matrix.

[image: API]

[image: API]

I already implemented the delta method.

```
public static double delta(Point2D.Double a, Point2D.Double b,
        Point2D.Double c) {
    return (a.getX() * b.getY() * 1) + ( a.getY() * 1 * c.getX()) + (1 * b.getX() * c.getY()) - (1 * b.getY() * c.getX())
            - (a.getX() * 1 * c.getY()) - (a.getX() * b.getY() * 1);
}
```

So How could I figure out if the line segments are disjoint or not ?

Comment: Can you do this by hand?

Answer (score 4):

Here's a solution for the **General Case**. See [this-page 9](http://www.dcs.gla.ac.uk/~pat/52233/slides/Geometry1x1.pdf) for special cases.

```
public static int orientation(Point p, Point q, Point r) {
    double val = (q.getY() - p.getY()) * (r.getX() - q.getX())
            - (q.getX() - p.getX()) * (r.getY() - q.getY());

    if (val == 0.0)
        return 0; // colinear
    return (val > 0) ? 1 : 2; // clock or counterclock wise
}

public static boolean intersect(Point p1, Point q1, Point p2, Point q2) {

    int o1 = orientation(p1, q1, p2);
    int o2 = orientation(p1, q1, q2);
    int o3 = orientation(p2, q2, p1);
    int o4 = orientation(p2, q2, q1);

    if (o1 != o2 && o3 != o4)
        return true;

    return false;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Point p1 = new Point(1,1);
    Point q1 = new Point(2,0);
    Point p2 = new Point(1,0);      
    Point q2 = new Point(3,2);      
    System.out.println("intersect: "+intersect(p1, q1, p2, q2));
}
```

Answer:
intersect: true

Answer (score 1):

The function delta is an implementation of the [cross product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product). This can be used to determine if points or vectors are clockwise or counterclockwise to each other. Two vectors are clockwise if `ab x cd > 0`, counterclockwise if `ab x cd < 0` and they are collinear if `ab x cd = 0`.

To use this to determine that two vectors intersect you can do the following:

Assume you have 4 points: a, b, c, d. Then you need to do 4 calculations:

```
(a - c) x (d - c) < 0
(b - c) x (d - c) > 0
```

With these 2 calculations you can determine if point `a` is counterclockwise and `b` is clockwise (or vice versa) to the vector `cd`. If this holds, the points are on different sides of the vector and this is what you need to have an intersection between them. Now you have to test `d` and `c` for the same.

```
(d - a) x (b - a) < 0
(c - a) x (b - a) > 0
```

If this also holds your two vectors intersect.

Edit: If all 4 calculations in this example are true, then there is an intersection of the vectors. This is true for the disjoint examples in your question, where no point is collinear with a vector. If you have to test this also then a collinear test is necessary.

The term `a - c` makes a vector out of two points.

```
a - c => ac.x = a.x - c.x, ac.y = a.y - c.y
```

Comment: So are you saying that if those 4 calculations are true then the two vectors intersect and if one of the 4 calculations is false then the vectors are disjoint ? And by saying (a-c), you mean the distance between point a and c ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you only need a true/false result in 2D space, there's an efficient way to compute this:

```
bool segmentsIntersect(Point2D a, Point2D b, Point2D c, Point2D d) {
    float det = (b.x - a.x) * (d.y - c.y) - (d.x - c.x) * (b.y - a.y);
    if (det == 0)
        return false; //Lines are parallel
    float lambda = ((d.y - c.y) * (d.x - a.x) + (c.x - d.x) * (d.y - a.y)) / det;
    float gamma = ((a.y - b.y) * (d.x - a.x) + (b.x - a.x) * (d.y - a.y)) / det;
    return (0 < lambda && lambda < 1) && (0 < gamma && gamma < 1);
}
```